# How to write Wrapper Class and using Visualforce page to display multiple objects data. Best Practises

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I want to display 2 objects like Job Deal object(Job Deal Code, Job)  and Recruiter Objects records fields in a single table. How to write VF page using wrapper class

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You'll find lots of examples if you search SFSE.

Comment: I am new to SF, trying to create VF page with wrapper class but i did not find right example. I will try searching again.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper class that you define will vary and depend on what you wish to achieve.

However, a common structure that most wrapper classes will follow is as below.

```
public class OuterClass{

    //OuterClassName properties...
    // use { get;set; } if you want to access the properties on VF
    
    public String property1;
    public Integer property2;
    public List<ObjectType> property3 { get;set; }
    
    // wrapperclass object
    public WrapperClass objWC;

    // Outer class constructor
    public OuterClass(){
        // do something
    }

    // Outer class methods
    public <returnType> method1(){
        // do something
    }

    public class WrapperClass{

    // wrapper class properties
    // use { get;set; } if you want to access the properties on VF
    
    public String wcProperty1;
    public Integer wcProperty2;
    public List<ObjectType> wcProperty3 {   get;set;    }
    
    // wrapper class constructor - could be parameterized or default
    public WrapperClass(){
    }

    public WrapperClass(String parameter1, Integer parameter2, ....){
        this.wcProperty1 = parameter1;
        this.wcProperty2 = parameter2;
        .
        .
        .
    }

    }

}
```

You would normally create an instance of the wrapper class either in constructor or a method of the outer class and assign values to the properties of the wrapper class.

```
WrapperClass wcobj = new wcobj();
wcobj.wcProperty1 = 'String Value';
wcobj.wcProperty2 = 2;
```

**OR**

```
WrapperClass wcobj = new wcobj('String Value', 2);
```

You can then display on the page by referring the property as `outerclass.wrapperclass.propertyName`

Most of the times you would be adding the wrapper objects into a list and may need to define a list like

```
List<WrapperClass> wrapperClassList = new List<WrapperClass>();
```

Comment: why there is no documentation on wrapper class in salesforce or APEX